# How to desing a URL pattern for /check?id=984c3a7b-766b-450e?

Tags: regex, django

I can't figure out how to design a regexp for `/check?id=984c3a7b-766b-450e?` url in django. I tried `r'^check\?id=(?P<id>[0-9a-f-]+)/$'` but it returns "Page Not Found". Works good with just `(?P<id>[0-9a-f-]+)` though.

Comment: There is no `/` at the end, there is a `?`, and your regex does not match it

Comment: This is a *qquerystring*, not part of the path, so you *can* not encode this in the `URL`, you need to inspect `request.GET` which acts like a `QueryDict`.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. thank you   Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/check?id=984c3a7b-766b-450e` is *not* part of the path, and can not be captured by Django's URL patterns. It is a `querystring`, and this is captured by the [**`request.GET`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET), a `QueryDict` object.

The `urlpatterns` thus look like:

```
# app/urls.py

from app.views import some_view
from django.urls import url

urlpatters = [
    url(r'^check$', some_view),
    # ...
]
```

and in the views, you can then obtain the value corresponding to the `id` key with:

```
# app/views.py

def some_view(request):
    my_id = request.GET['id']
    # ...
    # return a HttpResponse
```

`request.GET` acts more or less like a vanilla Python dictionary, except that a key can map to multiple values.